# Можно ли переписать данный метод с использованием EnumerateDirectories?

Tags: c#, .net

Не сказал бы, что у меня много папок, которые замедлят работу, но просто интересно.

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
            {
                Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
                queue.Enqueue(path);
                while (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    path = queue.Dequeue();
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))//Вот тут
                        {
                            queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                    foreach (string t in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
                    {
                        yield return t;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я хочу пополнять очередь и возвращать список файлов, одновременно.

Comment: ну замените GetDirectories на EnumerateDirectories и попробуйте. только есть нюанс, о котором вы возможно уже знаете. После создания EnumerateFiles/Directories не реагирует на изменение файловой системы после начала своей работы до следующего вызова, разве что исключение кинет если из под него файл удалить, но это я не проверял. Так что в этом смысле выгоды от него нет.

Comment: @rdorn, вроде, тут не достаточно сделать замену так как код дальше не пойдет пока не произойдет  'queue.Enqueue(subDir);'  всеми папками из директории.

Comment: кажется я вас понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите в одном цикле обработать и папки и файлы, то можно воспользоваться классом `DirectoryInfo` и переписать цикл так:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach(var fso in dir.EnumerateFileSystemInfos())
{
    if(fso is DirectoryInfo)
        queue.Enqueue(fso.FullName);
    if(fso is FileInfo)//перестраховка, по идее должно хватить просто else
        yield return fso.FullName;
}
```

---

Можно также воспользоваться перегрузкой метода `Directory.GetFiles` которая дает тот же результат:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Но с одним недостатком - метод упадет с исключением если у вашей программы, например не хватит прав на чтение какой-то папки.

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); при возникновении исключения сломается...

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, может сломаться, зависит от того с какими папками и правами работает программа, дополнил ответ