# Как скопировать все файлы из папки и её под папок?

Tags: c#

Не могу скопировать файлы из под папок основной директории

```
private static string GooVer = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile); // Директория от куда берём файлы.
private static string TxtPath = @"C:\" + UserName + @"\Отчёты\"; // Директория куда сохраняем файлы
private static readonly string[] Extensions = new string[] { "1402.txt","1908.doc"}; // форматы для файлов которые нужно скопировать.

    public static void CopyFiles()
    {
            foreach (string Rembo in Extensions)
            {
                string[] Inferno = Directory.GetFiles(GooVer, Rembo, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string Mic in Inferno)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(TxtPath);
                    File.Copy(Mic, TxtPath + Path.GetFileName(Mic));
                }
            }
    }
```

Код который выше копирует, но файлы которые лежат в под папках он не ищет!
Как сделать поиск во всех папках и в под папках?
Пробовал использовать `SearchOption.AllDirectories` но без результата!

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588643/198316 только учтите, что если к какому либо файлу или папке у вас не будет достаточно прав доступа, оно упадет с исключением, такие случаи нужно отдельно обрабатывать.

Comment: Мне бы как нибудь наверное нужно реализовать отдельно всё это, но не пойму как сделать сначала поиск в основной папке, а после в других, и уже как нибудь скопировать из всех папок + под папков все нужные файлы в 1 папку!

Comment: Можно и так сделать, пример обработки файлов и папок по отдельности в одном цикле, можно посмотреть тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577517/198316, только заменить обработку файлов и папок в ифах на то что вам нужно и добавьте маску поиска по необходимости. Ну или пишите подробности решаемой задачи, что имеете на входе, что хотите получить на выходе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1. Метод для получения файлов по маске (.Net 4.0+):

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   {
       Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
       //Здесь searchPatternExpression - это регулярное выражение для поиска файлов, например, \.mp3|\.mp4|\.doc или оставьте пустым для любых файлов.
       return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption).Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)));
   }
   ```

Если у вас не 4.0, а ниже, то вот аналогичный метод для .NET 3.5:

```
    public static string[] GetFilesNET35(string path, string searchPatternExpression, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        if (searchPatternExpression == null) searchPatternExpression = string.Empty;
        Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
        return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", searchOption).Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file))).ToArray();
    }
```

2. Если, к примеру, мы хотим все папки и файлы из директории **C:\App\Test\Path** перенести в **D:\NewPath** то нам еще понадобиться вот такой метод:

   ```
   public static string GetRelativeFileName(string BasePath, string FullPath)
   {
       if (FullPath.StartsWith(BasePath))
       {
           BasePath = BasePath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
           return FullPath.Replace(BasePath, string.Empty);
       }
       return string.Empty;
   }
   ```
3. Теперь в цикле копируем **ВСЕ** файлы (для не всех, а по выбору если - задайте маску для `GetFiles`):

   ```
   ...

   //Переменная для создания новых папок
   string newDir = string.Empty;

   string basePath = "Папка-источник";
   string newPath = "Целевая папка";

   //Переменная для короткого относительного имени файла (путь относительно базовой папки)
   string shortFilename = string.Empty;
   //Переменная для формирования нового имени файла
   string newFilename = string.Empty;

   //Делаем так, что бы наш новый путь всегда заканчивался на \ (обратный слэш) 
   newPath = newPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

   //Получаем список файлов:
   var files = GetFiles("Корневой путь для начала сканирования");
   //Обходим полученный список и копируем файлы и папки из базовой в целевую папку:
   foreach (var file in files) 
   {   
       //Вычисляем разницу между текущим и новым путём                     
       shortFilename = UT.GetRelativeFileName(basePath, file);
       //Задаем новый полный путь, куда будет скопирован файл 
       newFilename = newPath + shortFilename;
       //И узнаем папку, куда этот файл нужно положить будет
       newDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilename);
       //Если такой папки нет - создаем её:
       if (!Directory.Exists(newDir))
       {
           try
           {
               //Создание папки и всех сопутствующих папок:
               Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }
       }

       try
       {
            //Копируем старый файлик на новое место с замещением уже существующих (если вдруг там уже есть с таким именем файл)
            File.Copy(file, newFilename, true);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            throw e;
       }
   }
   ```

Вроде всё, только **не забудьте обязательно обработать ошибки должным образом**, а не просто кидать исключения, как в моём примере. Вам уже, например, говорили в комментах про возможность ошибок, связанных с правами доступа.

Код копировал из работающего реального приложения, слегка руками подчистив его и упростив (как раз удалил специфичную обработку ошибок и логирование). Должно работать, если ничего не напутал.