# Перебор файлов и копирование в определенную папку

Tags: c#

Как вызвать метод List?

```
public static void SearchAllFiles()
{
    List<String> files = new List<String>();
    String[] extensions = new String[] { "*.jpg", "*.txt", "*.asp" };

    foreach (String extension in extensions)
    {
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, found, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (String file in files)
            files.Add(file);
    }
}
```

И не могу сообразить в каком месте вставить копирование файлов:

```
 File.Copy(path, path + Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Comment: А зачем цикл по extenions? Смотря в каком моменте вы хотите копировать файлы там и вставляйте. И что за переменная found? Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories) не вернет вам все файлы из вложенных директорий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала сделаем метод для поиска файлов по маске. Работает с .NET 4.0 и быстрее, чем `Directory.GetFiles`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> nGetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption).Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)));
    }
```

Теперь так:

```
public static void SearchAllFiles()
{
    //Искомые расширения:
    string LookForExt = "\.jpg|\.txt|\.asp"; 
    //Пути папок источника и приёмника:
    string SourcePath = @"D:\SourceDir\";
    string TargetPath = @"D:\TargetPath\";
    //Получаем файлы и копируем их:
    IEnumerable<string> files = nGetFiles(SourcePath, LookForExt);
    foreach (f in files) //Можно было и так: foreach (f in nGetFiles(@"D:\SourceDir", LookForExt))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(f, TargetPath + Path.GetFileName(f), true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

В результате будут просканированы все файлы в папке `SourcePath` и ее подпапках, найденные файлы, соответствующие искомым расширениям будут скопированы в `TargetPath` *без сохранения* структуры подпапок. Более того, если есть файл `D:\SourceDir\test.asp` и есть файл `D:\SourceDir\111\test.asp`, то в результирующей папке `D:\TargetPath\` будет только один из этих файлов, который будет копироваться последним (он и перезатрёт существующий, и скопированный первым в целевую папку файл).

Если же нужно скопировать файлы из папки с сохранением структуры вложенных папок и файлов, то [вот тут уже давал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/589492/222168).

Comment: Попробовал Ваш метод,копирует не все файлы, только `.txt` форматы, почему не все файлы копируются?

Comment: @ArteS, а какие файлы в исходной папке были? Фильтр по файлам задаётся вот тут: `string LookForExt = "\.jpg|\.txt|\.asp";`

Comment: Да именно там и добавлял расширения к файлам, но выходило так, копируется только `"\.txt"` формат, и пару файлов формата `"\.jpg"`. Почему такое происходит?

Comment: Странно, но попробуйте заменить еще `foreach (f in files)` на `foreach (f in nGetFiles(@"D:\SourceDir", LookForExt))`.

У меня такой проблемы не возникало, вот в чём штука, код используется в реальной программе.

Comment: Если в директорию-источник закинуть только *.jpg в количестве 10 штук, то они скопируются?

Comment: Заработало) замена в `foreach (f in nGetFiles(@"D:\SourceDir", LookForExt)){}`, теперь копирует нормально.

Comment: @ArteS, видимо, что-то с итератором не то получалось (сложно сказать, не зная деталей). Но рад, что заработало в итоге.

Comment: Измените цикл `foreach (f in files)` на `foreach (var f in files)`, Вы не дописали малёх =)

Answer (score 3):

Создаете массив с расширениями, в цикле пробегаетесь по нему и ищите файлы с нужным расширением, дальше пробегаетесь в цикле по всем найденным файлам одного расширения и копируете по одному в нужную директорию, в моем случае копирование из `D:\files` в `D:\files\copied`

```
public static void SearchAllFiles()
{
    string path = @"D:\files\"; // откуда
    string pathTo = @"D:\files\copied\"; // куда

    string[] extensions = { "*.jpg", "*.txt", "*.asp" };

    foreach (string ext in extensions)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(path + Path.GetFileName(file), pathTo + Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Еще можно убрать цикл по `extensions`, заменив поиск файлов на `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
           .Where(s => extensions.Any(e => s.EndsWith(e))`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за примеры, буду вникать, так же хотелось узнать на .Net 2.0 выше способ ускорить возможно?

Comment: @ArteS, да. Вместо EnumerateFiles вызываете GetFiles.

Comment: @Vlad, И последний вопрос: Можно ли сделать обход на определенную папку, например мне нужно запретить проходить папку Users, так как в ней тоже много папок и файлов, как сделать обход?

Comment: @ArteS, как сделать это, используя метод `GetFiles` я не знаю. Как вариант, можно добавить еще условие выборки к примеру выше:  `.Where(_ => !_.Contains(Path.Combine(path, "Users")))`